# Convergence of series over a complex lattice

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently working on my bachelor thesis that is on the J-Invariant. I am working with Apostol, Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory, and I have encountered a lemma I would like to get some inspiration for a proof for.

The lemma is as follows,

*If $\alpha$>2 and L' is a lattice without the zero element, then the series,
$$\sum_{\omega\in L'}\frac{1}{\omega^\alpha}$$
converges absolutely.*

I originally followed the proof from Apostol, which is dividing the lattice into layers, deciding on the biggest and smallest length to the layer to the origin, counting the amount of lattice points in each layer and then comparing the terms from the series with the observations from before.

It is a nice intuitive proof, but I feel like it is hard to do without replicating it. So do anyone have a nice idea? I just want some guidance and inspiration, NOT a full proof.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler proof is to use a 2D integral comparison test. Note that  after you delete any region centered at the origin of the $\omega$ plane, the improper double  integral $\int \int \frac{1}{|\omega|^p} \ dA$
is convergent when $p>2$.

P.S. Here is how you justify this integral comparison test in two dimensions. Consider any lattice cell that excludes the origin. Note that $|\omega |$ attains it max and min at the corners of the lattice cell.  Use this fact to show that the integral over the given lattice cell is sandwiched between two values of the lattice summand. Now sum over all lattice cells in the tiling of the infinite region. This sandwiching of lattice sums and integrals shows that the sum is absolutely convergent iff the integral is convergent.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will look into it!